# Disable "Confirm Save to Web Server"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Everytime when I try to close my Visual Studio I receive a message:

> A more recent version of the file
>
> "FILE_PATH/FILE_NAME" has been saved to the web on 'DATE_TIME'.
>
> Do you want to replace the server file with your local file?
>
> [Yes] or [No]

Well, I always click "NO", but i receive this message again when I re-open the Visual Studio.

This is annoying me, and each passing day, more and more files are "theoretically Most Recent"

Anyone knows how to disable this message, permanently?

> Visual Studio 2012 Update 4

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/531487/constantly-prompted-with-do-you-want-to-replace-the-server-file-with-your-local-file)  please, it seems to be a bug

Comment: You are right. This is a bug, and microsoft know that. 

[link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1486851.aspx?FTP+Confirm+Save+To+Web+Server+modified+by+unknown+)